# Making a row for labels in a Google visualisation

Tags: google-visualization

I've got a Google chart timeline showing the start times for various parts of a project and what the lag will be in us being able to measure the effects of the project. Currently my labels are tiny because Google insists on putting the labels to the left, right, or inside the box. I could make my chart a lot clearer if the labels were in a blank row beneath the boxes. Before I hack away adding blank lines then edit it in paint, is there a sensible way to move where the labels appear, and to add blank lines?

Example:

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
        var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Project' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
        dataTable.addRows([
        ['Project A', 'Start Project', new Date(2017,0), new Date(2017,1)],

        ['Project B', 'Start Project', new Date(2027,0), new Date(2027,1)],

        [ 'Project C',  'Start project',    new Date(2018, 3),  new Date(2018, 4) ],
        [ 'Project C', 'Some stuff happens before the official start of project', new Date(2018,0), new Date(2018,1)],
        [ 'Project C' , 'Observable statistic has changed due to project', new Date(2018,7), new Date(2018,8)]
        ])
        var options = {
            timeline: { colorByRowLabel: true ,
                barLabelStyle: {fontSize:8},
                rowLabelStyle: {fontSize:10}
                }
        };
        chart.draw(dataTable, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="timeline" style="height: 1800px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: no easy solution, would have to turn off labels and manually add them to the chart's svg, once the chart's `'ready'` event fires...

Comment: Donno about your case. But by look-wise it may look less attractive if u keep a seperative row for labels. U may can show them in tooltip instead (less messy). Jus sayin.